# South Georgia Island and Settlement

Tags: climate-change

I know there were settlements in South Georgia in the past, but they were all abandoned. Is there any environmental reason why a new settlement could not be made? Especially with global warming, the climate has gotten warmer.

Comment: In what sense do you mean environmental? Natural environment requiring protection from human interference or climate related reasons.

Comment: @Fred Are there any reasons weather or geological wise that make settlement not possible

Comment: @a_donda well, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grytviken It was inhabited until 1966 by whalers, so the last century

Comment: All settlements are not abandoned, there are people permanently at King Edward Point: https://www.bas.ac.uk/polar-operations/sites-and-facilities/facility/king-edward-point/ Officially for science purpose, although their presence also has a political aspect, as Argentina claims the island. But I won't go into politics! :)